# How to echo a input from one docker container to another

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

I am working with 2 docker container, container 1: when running it asks user for input for example “what’s your name”, store it. Container 2: takes the user input from container 1 and echo’s “hello

test.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo “What’s your name?”
read -p “Enter your name: “ username 
echo “Hello $username!”
```

```
Dockerfile:

FROM ubuntu 
COPY test.sh ./
ENTRYPOINT [ “./test.sh”]
```

Comment: Use netcat / socat or write an application that transfers the mentioned data over tcp

Comment: You can even just `docker run container1 | docker run container2`.

Comment: Do I need to create two dockerfile or two bash script?

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the two containers together, using the `docker network connect` command. More information on the following webpage,

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/

Comment: Do I need to add anything in my dockerfile or script file to call for container 2?

Comment: Your container 2, needs to communicate with container 1 Maybe creating a volume approach might be better, both containers would have access to this volume, and container 1 would store the file in the volume, while container 2 can read the file from the volume after. More information at the following link https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/